# bootstrap 4: difference between adding a row or adding a col-12?

Tags: html, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to clarify this doubt, but on the documentation on bootstrap 4 isn't specified.

What is the difference between these two snippet:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">col-12</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
   <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And, just using a single .row:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">col-12</div>
   <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
   <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

That is: adding a specific new .row, or simply adding a col-12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add more than col-12 to a row, bootstrap system simply breaks after col-12 in your example.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">col-12</div>
   <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
   <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Writing like this is totally fine.

Comment: so basically, both are fine and can be used. At this point I prefer this choice since i don't have to add another .row

Comment: That's exactly what I do most of the time. It is also useful if you add columns by a function and have no idea how many columns will follow.

Comment: If you use "row" you can be sure that a new row starts. If you rely on cols and at some point change the cols then you will also have to adapt all following cols to ensure the wrapping is still correct.